# Scrollbar not scrolling completely down the page

Tags: html, css

I have this minor issue. I have a main div with class `scroll`. I have several other input parameters where I take input from the user. This inputs fills up the entire page vertically.

Now I minimize the screen with Chrome minimize button. (i.e. restore down button). The page gets shrinked and a scrollbar shows up since it is set to `overflow:scroll`.

Now the problem is that it does not scroll till the end of the page. suppose there are 20 input parameters and when I minimize, I can scroll up to 18th input parameter only. Scrollbar doesn't go beyond 18 and hides the last 2 so the viewer is not able to see.

```
<div class="scroll">
</div>
<!-- Added this extra div below and now able to scroll the last 2 parameters as well -->
<div style="height:50px;">
</div>

.scroll {
height:100%;
overflow:scroll; 
}
```

Can someone please let me know if I did anything wrong.

Comment: Is it hiding behind the system task bar or on another display?

Comment: not sure wat u meant. When i hold the mouse and maximize the widnow by dragging the lower part of page, i can see the last 2 parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not sure what the possible cause was. But just putting an extra div below the regular div solved the issue. Now i can view all the items in the above div. Please see the question itself for the answer. 
Might help someone in case they want to have a workaround like this.

Comment: The same happened with me.

Comment: Really a hack but it did solve the issue for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

possible causes:

- A vertical offset like `margin-top: 100px` or `top: 100px` combined with `height: 100%` when using `position: absolute;`. In this case change to `height: calc(100% - 100px);`
- The same with `padding-top` or `padding-bottom`. Possible solution: `box-sizing: border-box;`

But without code all this is guessing...

Comment: Setting height according to @Johannes worked for me. height: calc(100% - 100px);

Answer (score 5):

Replacing `height` with `min-height` should fix this.

Change this:

```
.scroll {
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll; 
}
```

To this:

```
.scroll {
    min-height:100%;
    overflow:scroll; 
}
```

Comment: tried it. it doesnot work. however if i set height:300px or height:800px, i can see a scrollbar. What could be the issue ?

Comment: hmm, if that's the case, try adding a `min-height` of 800px and `height` of 100% and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: i added an extra div below that and gave a height to it. now scrolling can get to the last parameter in the above div. Please see edited code in my question. Can you tell me what could be the issue now. thanks for all the inputs

Answer (score 2):

```
.scroll{
height: calc(100vh - 100%);
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If above solutions are not working for you you can just add a negative margin to the scrollbar. Is just a come around than an actual solution, but it did the job for me.

```
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
        margin-top: -10px;
        margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solved it by applying `overflow:hidden` to the immediate parent container.

Assuming you have a section inside a container that you want to apply a scroll to. First make sure that the container holding the section is given `overflow:hidden` then go ahead to apply the `overflow:scroll` to the child section.

worked for me.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

padding-bottom, to the div with the scroll bar, is your friend.

```
.scroll {
  height:100%;
  overflow:scroll; 
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hope it will solve*

```
.scroll{margin-bottom : 50px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and it was solved by removing the "main" section in the layout page.

Initially:

```
        <div class="container">
            <main role="main" class="pb-3 d-flex flex-nowrap" st>
                @RenderBody()
                <partial name="_Notification" />
            </main>

        </div>
```

Modified, which solved the problem:

```
        <div class="container">
                @RenderBody()
                <partial name="_Notification" />
        </div>
```

I already checked the css files (e.g. bootstrap) for size restrictions in the main class. But didn´t find anything...

I suppose there´s an issue with HTML 5. But this is just an excpectation.

If anyone else will find the origin, i´m quiet interessted in ;-)

Best regards
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem where i had the bootstrap element(table-responsive) with height in vh.
When i replaced the vh unit with px, i got it solved

```
.element{
height:700px;
overflow:auto;
}
```